# %2f or other special character in common vfs

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

Recently, I meet a problem when resolve file path by commons-vfs.

```
  FileObject tmpDestFo = fsm.resolveFile("/tmp/tempfile%2flicense.xml");
  tmpDestFo.copyFrom(destFo);
```

As the example, what I expect after the copying is a file named 'tempfile%2flicense.xml' is created under '/tmp' directory. But the result is a file named 'license.xml' created in the '/tmp/tempfile' directory.

I think it's caused by the resolveFile API which replace the character '%2f' to '/'. I'm not sure about if other special characters are processed in the same way.

Do you have some idea about the problem? I do want a file whose name include the '%2f'.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add a Backslash `(\)` before %

Answer (score 0):

`resolveFile()` requires an URI, you actually need to escape quite a few characters. You can run a file path through an URL encode, or you can use `new File("/tmp/tempfile%2flicense.xml").toURI().toString()` (at least for sane file names).

In your case you need to replace `%` with `%25`: "/tmp/tempfile%252flicense.xml"

BTW: The %2f is an encoded /, are you sure it is supposed to be named that way?